# Find the specified text in html and format it

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I please find all the text in an HTML page that is enclosed in square brackets and set it, say, in bold?

Example:
My webpage text, [some] embedded in square [brackets].

Result:
My webpage text, [**some**] embedded in square [**brackets**].

Thank you.
Kamil

Comment: Is your text inside `<p>` tags?

Comment: Yes, it is, but the DOM structure is:

<div class="markdown-html css-fb3dw2"> = $0
 <p>
  "[ENV] Nodes"
  ::after
 </p>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

replace it using regex

```js
var bracket = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = bracket.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, "[<strong>$1</strong>]")
```

```html
<p>My webpage text, [some] embedded in square [brackets].</p>
```